# how to Install go-junit-report if its not installed - in build.sh

Tags: bash, go, installation

dpkg --status for nano or sudo works but for "go" or for "go-junit-report" - it doesn't work. So my question is how can programmatically check whether go-junit-report is installed or not and if its not installed then install it.

for installation: `go get github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report`

Tried below -***doesn't work***:

```
if ! type "go-junit-report -version" > /dev/null; then
  ## Install JUnit for golang for XML based report
go get github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is partially working for me (at least its invoking go get github..):

```
if hash go-junit-report 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "go-junit-report installed"
    else
        go get github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report
    fi
```